# Не стартует selenium в хроме

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

объясните, что не так. Путь указан верно:

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = "https://www.google.ru/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Desktop/driver/chromdriver')
driver.get(link)
```

Вот лог:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromdriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: О какой ОС идет речь?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Comment: @ Alexey R MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил полной переустановкой Хрома и хромдрайвера. Все взлетело. Видимо хром слишком старый был

Comment: Да, версии хрома и хромдрайвера должны быть совместимы. Хотя на эту тему обычно выходит ошибка, где прямо написано, какая версия нужна.